# CDC 6600 system console

Tags: cdc

The CDC 6600 system console was a vector drawing system with a single font that also provided a way of drawing simple graphics ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDC_6000_series#Display_console)).

In simple terms how does this vector drawing system work?

Further, how did the dual screens operate and how were they used? Particularly interesting may be the simple graphics functionality.

An additional but lesser question is what font was used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In simple terms how does this vector drawing system work?

Like essentially like an oscilloscope. A beam is used to draw on the screen, controlled by two voltages for X/Y. Not much different as a TV, except with TV the movement is fixed as lines left to right and top down.

***In very simple terms:*** (*1)

A CRT is a huge tube with a heated electrode supplying a constant stream of electrons (*2) focused to hit another electrode which happens to be the screen. When an electron hits, its energy gets turned into photons aka light. The beam can be modulated (on/off) and directed by applying voltage to a set of coils. One deflecting in horizontal direction. Negative for up, positive for down. The other coil does the same vertical. Positive to the right, negative to the left. Changing the voltage allows to draw any arbitrary set of lines or vectors as they are called.

For a text vector display one would sort all vectors for the letters to be drawn in sequence of characters and vectors within a character.

For musings about how such displays can be made, take a looks at this question:

[What are principles of vector CRT display?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14736/what-are-principles-of-vector-crt-display-simplest-way-to-drive-crts)

In case of the 6600 console all drawing was done from CPU memory by a dedicated I/O processor, which reads a stream of XY coordinate to be drawn and sends them to a DA converter within the console to to be turned into voltages to the coils to deflect the beam.

*[In some way this is a bit like used by 'cheap video' and later Sinclair's ZX80/81 computers. The (A) CPU (Peripheral Processor) feeds a data structure in RAM to a rather primitive video hardware only doing the signal conversion.]*

> Further, how did the dual screens operate and how were they used?

Simply as two screens. One for interactive input one for a log. Or one as system console one as user output (graphics). There was no hardware preference for either screen. Much like today one could use two windows on a PC - or two screens.

Of course users got creative - like with every new toy. There was a chess program that did draw board and pieces on one screen while having a textual list of all moves on the other. And then there was eventually the first implementation of the 'EYES' program, well known from X-Window. Here each screen displayed an eye, both looking around (synchronized), blinked and so on. Of course not following a mouse pointer, but it could be controlled.

> Particularly interesting may be the simple graphics functionality.

It wasn't simple (*3) in any way, as next to arbitrary vector graphic could be displayed. As a rough estimation a peripheral processor can output one value per micro second, two are needed for a vector, or 500,000 vectors per second. Lets say we want to keep the refresh rate at 50 Hz (*4), then a graphic displayed can be made up from up to 10,000 lines - more with lower refresh rates (*5).

> An additional but lesser question is what font was used?

A readable? Not sure what you expect as an answer here. At this time in history there were no artistic choices. It was all about getting some text out - which was already seen as a major achievement. What can be said is that characters were designed to use as little vectors (strokes, visible or invisible) as possible, as the total number of vectors displayed defined the refresh rate.

Characters were thus rather angled, but seamed, thanks to their vector nature way more clean and readable than any contemporary raster display:

[image]

*(Picture taken a cray-cyber.org [blog entry](https://cray-cyber.org/cdc-cyber-960-starts-after-8-years/))*

The "CONTROL DATA 6600 COMPUTER SYSTEM DATA CHANNEL EQUIPMENT - DIAGRAMS & CIRCUIT DESCRIPTION" document (from [Bitsavers](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/cdc/cyber/cyber_70/fieldEngr/60125000C_6602_6603_6622_6681_6682_Data_Channel_Diagrams_Dec65.pdf)), contains a series of pages that describe the geometry of the characters.

[image: Page 26]

Worth noting that the response of the analog circuits distorted the symbols, giving them a whimsical handwritten look.

[image: The "handwritten" look]

*(Captured (2:52) from [Control Data CDC 6600 Supercomputer (Naval Weather Global tracking Climate) 1972](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wcSmUEaCRp8))*

The shown CC545 console is a later model. Workings are still the same, including the ability to produce two pictures, but only a single CRT is used. A switch, labeled left/right, seen in the lower left, beside the keyboard, is provided to select between either output , here set to display the right screen.

---

*1 - REALLY simple. It's as simple as I can. So please, no arguing about finer details, correct names, etc.

*2 - In a tube the electrode emitting the electron ray is called cathode - hence the name *Cathode Ray Tube* or short *CRT*.

*3 - I guess the one adding that wording would qualify all vector display as 'simple' in hindsight.

*4 - Refresh rate on vector displays is not a constant but depends on the number of vectors displayed.

*5 - 50 Hz is a rather high refresh rate for vector displays, as these displays do usually feature a longer persistence than later raster screens. As low as 20 Hz can be still fine.

Comment: This is the kind of answer was looking for. So the vector refers to referencing a point by x and y coordinates, not a straight line on the console output? The clean and readable display is well-demonstrated in the picture—interesting to know was superior to the contemporary raster displays. Was this partly due to having a higher pixel density?

Comment: Morgen frueh editlib laufen lassen? JA

Comment: @SingleMalt No, it does draw lines. It does not have pixels. Output is essentially a series of 'DRAW-TO' commands, either with the cannon enabled, thus producing a line, or cannon disabled, resulting in a repositioning. So for all practical purpose the the pixel density between two points was indeinite. What was quantisized is the number of addressablepositions for start or end of a line/positioning,which was (IIRC) 12 bit, or 4096x4096 possiblelocations.

Comment: @OmarL Ja :)) The stickers are still preserved from the original installation, before the machine was taken out of service. We believe that these machines tell a story, and 'restoring' to a clean, better than new state is essentially destroying its history.

Comment: More w.r.t. lack of pixels:  On a monochrome display the entire surface of the CRT is a uniform phosphor coating.  A vector display can draw anywhere on it, and in continuous lines.  A color CRT had either stripes or dots of different color phosphors (this is _independent_ of the "pixel' nature of the raster scan displays!) and that led to graininess and lack of resolution.  There is no display as clear as a high resolution monochrome display and I'd gladly go back to one in an instant - if it accepted modern interfaces - and leave behind the "color coded syntax" of modern IDEs.

Comment: So there are not really pixels in the vector display—as the beam moves from one of the 4096x4096 addressable possibilities to a different one, the beam will cross multitudes of phosphor coating. This is the reason for such high resolution? Separately, the reason for having two displays is that the positioning of the beam would require much higher tolerances for a single larger display?

Comment: There are two reasons for the high resolution: First, it isn't scanning horizontal lines but writing anywhere on a uniform plane, and second, _extremely_ accurate (and fast) digital-to-analog converters, frequently including (analog or possibly digital) circuitry to make sure that when the beam changed position the lag in beam direction (due to electomagnetic effects) where accounted for.

Comment: @davidbak so there was not much “momentum”, when a change in direction occurred the beam moved precisely due to these DACs?

Comment: @SingleMalt - I don't think "momentum" is the right word - I'm not sure of the right word actually - but the beam direction is affected by inductance and capacitance in the circuitry changing the electric and/or magnetic fields controlling the beam, and that causes corners to get rounded off, or overshot, depending.

Comment: By the way, I get that the CDC 6000 console CRTs had 12 bit addressing in each axis (therefore 4096x4096) but I'd be very surprised if you actually _got_ 12 bit accuracy in beam positioning back then (mid 60s).

Comment: @davidbak Yes and no. Even with 1960s hardware the output would be 4096x4096 points (when adjusted right). What it may not be is exactly even spaced grid location. Depending on screen curvature, deflection curve and alike two points in a set distance in the middle may be a bit further apart than two points at the same relative distance further out. Still, results are good enough for most usages - including text, despite the fact that the human eye is very good at detecting irregulärstes. Not to mention that a picture at all was already a big thing at the time.

Comment: See here for some details about the character generator: http://www.classiccmp.org/pipermail/cctalk/2018-June/040263.html

Comment: "Not much different as a TV, except with TV the movement is fixed as lines left to right and top down" - except with a CRT TV, the beam deflection is achieved using electromagnets, not charged plates.

Comment: @JeremyP This depends much on your value of TV, as plates have been used in early TV as well. After all, copper is a lot more expensive than voltage, plus magnetic linearity needs more circuitry. Last but not least, it took some time to develop modern, low depth CRT, didn't it?

Comment: @Raffzahn Early TVs, but not most TVs. The point stands.

Comment: @JeremyP did you notice the topic?  Beside the fact, the method of deflection is neither topic nor relevant to the answer. What good is it to jump around a very narrow point about an irrelevant detail? There's nothing to gain for readers by doing so. Just proving half baked understanding of aspects at work.

Comment: @Raffzahn I'm commenting on a sentence in your answer that is incorrect: "A beam is used to draw on the screen, controlled by two voltages for X/Y. Not much different as a TV, except with TV the movement is fixed as lines left to right and top down". It's not true in general for a TV. The only reason anybody is jumping around on a narrow point is that *you* have decided that a valid criticism is not to be accepted. If you had just said "yeah, that's true for the majority of TVs" or had ignored it or had corrected your statement, this would not be a thing.

Comment: @JeremyP Not sure what this good for. You're trying hard to make a point about something that has neither been topic nor written. Neither global as part of the question, nor local in the paragraph you're citing from. It seems you inserted some overly detailed assumptions not called for. Trying to 'criticise' a statement that has been introduced by you in the first place is futile. I admit, I made an error by letting in to your argumentation to show that it's even invalid within your own frame of reference. That was wrong. I should have simply pointed out that you need to reread it.

Comment: @Raffzahn As I said in my last comment, it is you who is making something out of nothing. I made a comment that is a minor correction to a minor fact in your article and you seem to have gone off on one.

Answer (score 4):

Specifically a sub-answer with respect to fonts:  Don't know about the CDC 6600 but in the vector graphics world the [*Hershey fonts*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hershey_fonts) ruled - at least until the very late 70's, early 80's.  And for plotters - perhaps even later, as they were provided by all the plotting libraries you could get.

[Here are some examples](https://web.archive.org/web/20111116000733/http://idlastro.gsfc.nasa.gov/idl_html_help/Hershey_Vector_Font_Samples.html#wp1050826) of what they looked like, and [here is Hershey's original technical report](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Calligraphy_for_Computers/qFFCAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) which has more information than you ever wanted to know about the constraints under which they were designed, and how they were designed (including mathematical formulas!).

(Almost forgot: Extremely important in establishing their ubiquity was that they were *free*! Developed at great expense and with great care by the US military they were available for all to use.)

Here's "Simplex Roman":

[image: Hershey's "Simplex Roman" font]

And here's "Complex Script" which was for some reason very widely used, even though even back then - not to mention now to the modern eye - it looked like ... well, hmm, amateur?  (If not worse.)

[image: ![enter image description here]

(Answer truthfully, you prefer *Comic Sans* to that, right?)

Comment: Interesting to know about this. The CDC 6600 was released in 1964 so slightly predates these fonts (Wikipedia says circa 1967). But it could be that they shared a common ancestor design.

Comment: @SingleMalt it wasn't terribly difficult to design your own vector font.  I did one around 1974 or so.  P.S. that Simplex Script looks a lot like MS Script for Windows, I wonder if that's where they obtained it?

Comment: @MarkRansom That vector fonts were not difficult to design your own is interesting. Further, the Hershey Wikipedia page says that vector fonts are easily scaled and rotated in two or three dimensions. “Some glyphs were developed in four different versions, dubbed Simplex, Duplex, Complex and Triplex, which used different numbers of strokes to compose their contours” [again Wikipedia], suggesting further flexibility. The two example fonts above are simplex, so common terminology was in use.

Comment: Great addition, but to my knowledge these fonts were only used with plotters when it was about high quality output, as they require a huge amount of points to be addressed (line on/off doesn't matter). Character display is limited by the number of points that can be reached within a reasonable (variable) refresh time. Thus character shapes were usually kept to a low point count each, resulting in way more edged/pointy shapes. essentially making them look more like on a 16 segment LED than above nice shapes. The CDC used already an above average granularity, enabled due the way it created them.

Comment: @Raffzahn - but also with Tek storage tubes ... I know I used them that way ... I know that's not what the OP was asking about with the CDC 6600 display ...

Comment: @davidbak This wasn't meant as any critizism at all. Just a footnote. Storage tubes have the same advantage as plotter - many more points can be used as the image doesn't vanish (as fast).